# MS Azure : Not Able To Copy Azure Cloud File To Another Directory

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files, azure-files

I am trying to copy a Cloud File from one directory to another, within same File-Share account but facing issue.

**Code:**

Below is the code I am using, following article ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#copy-files )

```
public bool ArchiveTheFile(string filename)
    {
        bool fileCopied = false;
        try
        {
            var fileshare = ResolveCloudFileShare();
            if (fileshare.Exists())
            {
                CloudFileDirectory rootDir = fileshare.GetRootDirectoryReference();
                CloudFileDirectory dirSource = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Azure.Storage.FileShare.Source"]);
                CloudFileDirectory dirArchive = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Azure.Storage.FileShare.Destination"]);

                // Ensure that the directory exists.
                if (dirSource.Exists())
                {
                    // Get a reference to the file we created previously.
                    CloudFile sourceFile = dirSource.GetFileReference(filename);

                    // Ensure that the file exists.
                    if (sourceFile.Exists())
                    {
                        // Ensure that the directory exists.
                        if (dirArchive.Exists())
                        {
                            // Get a reference to the destination file.
                            CloudFile destFile = dirArchive.GetFileReference(filename);
                            destFile.StartCopy(sourceFile);fileCopied =true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return fileCopied ;
    }
```

**Below is the error :**

Not able to use **StartCopy()** method of **CloudFile** class

**1. Screenshot of error :**

[image]

Object returning by GetFileReference() do not have StartCopy() method :

[image]

**2. Error Message :**

*'CloudFile' does not contain a definition for 'StartCopy' and no extension method 'StartCopy' accepting a first argument of type 'CloudFile' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?*

Please Note: 
I am already using below two assembly reference:

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File;

Comment: Any more details? I test it in my site and it works fine. How do you authenticate your source file?

Comment: I am authenticating using Access Key. I am not facing problem accessing the files. **Issue Is: _Code is not getting compiled because of the error. I am not able to see StartCopy() function of CloudFile object (destFile)_**. Am I missing any Assembly/Reference here ?

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing the right CloudFile? if you hover the mouse over CloudFile, what binary is it coming from?

Comment: Please tell us about the version of Storage SDK for .Net you're using.

Comment: 1. **CloudFile** is comming from **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File**  2. **Version** : 4.3.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` package to latest version or at least 5.0.2. `StartCopy` for `CloudFile` is not supported until version 5.0.2.

Comment: Thanks Jerry,  I have updated the same to latest version ( 9.1.1 ) & this fixed the issue